# Reading and replacing lines in java

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I'm attempting to read the file.txt into java line by line and then when a line is "foo" I set the line after it to be "lineAfterFoo" then output that to the user.

My Java Code....

```
public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
        FileReader someFile = new FileReader("file.txt");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(someFile);
        int i = 0;
        String[] line;
        line = new String[10];
        line[i] = input.readLine();

            while(line[i] != null) {

                line[i] = input.readLine();

                if (line[i] == "foo") {
                    i = i + 1;

                    line[i] = "lineAfterFoo";
                }

                i = i + 1;

            }

            for (int number = 1; number < i; number++) {
                System.out.println(line[number]);
            }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

File.txt

```
1
2
3
foo
HopeFullyThisWillChange
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

The Error...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main"
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `main` method must be `static`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // snip...  
}
```

---

#### Edit - onto solving the real problem

The loop only runs once because, after the first pass through the `while` body, `i` will be equal to `1`. At that point `line[1]` is null, because you haven't read anything into it. Here's the typical idiom used instead (**note the changes in variable names**):

```
int i = 0;
String line = null;
String[] lines = new String[10];

// read the next line and immediately check to see if it's null
// also make sure that i doesn't go out of range
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null
    && i < lines.length) {
    lines[i] = line;

    // Use .equals() (not ==) when comparing strings!
    if ("foo".equals(line)) {
        i++; // shorter form of i=i+1
        lines[i] = "lineAfterFoo";
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: WOW I missed that... I changed it to static but now It looks like the while loop is only running once. any ideas?

Comment: @User: yes, but I recommend that you try to solve this one on your own first. Try stepping through your code with a debugger to figure out why the loop only runs once. Here's a hint: it's because line[i] is null after the first pass through, and `i` will be equal to `1` at that point.

Comment: @User: I've edited my answer to show you how to start fixing your code.

Comment: I just figured it out, my way was... well more basic but it got the job done :)

Comment: @User: if you take away from nothing else from my answer: **use `equals()`, not `==`, for Strings**.

Comment: the i++ was also helpful, thanks! I also had to add input.readLine(); after lines[i] = "lineAfterFoo"; so it wouldn't output both.

Answer (score 0):

This error is not related to your code at all, you're simply trying to execute the wrong class. Check your IDE configuration, and test on the command line with `java MyMainClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `main` need to be `static`?

Comment: My answer answers your answer's question. ;-)

Comment: For sooth, it does.  Your answer is of higher quality than mine.:)